# data=data={...} How to delete the first data= from such strings?

Tags: python, string, split

I got `data=....` where I've done splitting so `text.split("=")` and chose the second list element.

But with my new data in this way it deletes even the data= and the `"{" "}"` Elements

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You should choose the second element through the end of the list, then rejoin them.

```
text = "=".join(text.split("=")[1:])
```

Or you could do a string replacement:

```
text = text.replace("data=data=", "data=")
```